# Trust anchor for certification path not found in localhost (Android studio insecure communication)

Tags: android, ssl, https, communication

I'm following this guide for an university project: https://checkmarx.github.io/Kotlin-SCP/m3-insecure-communication/
The attack works properly, but when I change to https i get that error. Googling I've seen that maybe the problem is Android, because the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate works on local so my phone doesn't recognize it as a valid certificate (?)
Perhaps I'm not setting the certificate from Let's Encrypt right. Can someone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. This page is supposed to help but I don't know how the network_security_config.xml file should loook like for localhost: https://developer.android.google.cn/training/articles/security-config#CustomTrust